# iTunes playback skipping on some songs

Tags: windows-7, itunes, music, media-player, digital-audio

A client of mine has called me with a bizarre problem.  The PC he runs his music from (~200GB of it) uses iTunes and it has started skipping (or stuttering) at the start of some songs when the previous song finishes and it moves to the next song by itself.  Ie. when it's left to play continually.
He's also noticed that the time stalls at about 9 seconds and then resumes at 12 seconds.

In an effort to fix this issue - amongst others he has with PC performance - I replaced his suspect 500GB SATA2 drive with a new 1TB SATA3 drive (ghosted the old HDD) and installed an additional 4GB DDR2 RAM into his machine.

The system performance is greatly improved, but the unusual iTunes issue remains.   I say unusual because I myself have roughly 140GB of music in my personal collection and have never come across this issue before.

Any suggestions?  (No, the songs are not corrupt - they play and progress fine in other media players).

Comment: has to be a motherboard issue, i'd reinstall windows just to rule it out, but that's what i would point at.

Comment: I was suspecting that also after working with it.  There's a few bulged caps that may indicate some issues with the SB for sound.
I'll see if I can get more time with it to do a reinstall.